# Pandas CSV difference comparison when matching IDs

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In two CSV files, there's one file with extra columns that talk about different fields, and I was wondering how to highlight those columns that were different.

Let's say this is CSV1,

```
ID | StartDate |   EndDate  |  Poop | Name
 1 |  2-Jun-10 | 31-Oct-99  | Poop1 | Poopy
 2 |  1-Jun-10 | 30-Oct-98  | Poop2 | Butt
 3 |  1-Jun-90 | 1-Jun-99   | Poop3 | Hole
```

and given these columns, CSV2 respectively:

```
ID | StartDate | Name
 1 |  2-Jun-12 | Poopy
 2 |  1-Jun-12 | Butt
 4 | 1-Jun-14  | Ew
```

How would I be able to:
Highlight differences in columns? (i.e. when matching the ID and finding the differences, highlight differences in Columns that are the same, i.e. one thing appears in CSV1 but not CSV2 in the same column)

So the result of these tables would be:

"In CSV2 Name: Ew doesn't appear in CSV1, as shown by ID: 4 not existing in CSV1"

"In CSV1 Name: Hole doesn't appear in CSV2, as shown by ID: 3 not existing in CSV2"

Thanks in advance since I'm getting wrecked and it seems simple to do manually, but not sure how to code it. I've tried this so far:

```
import item as item
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\poop1.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
csv2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\poop2.csv', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
csv1.head()
csv1.equals(csv2)
print(csv2[~csv2.ID.isin(csv1.ID)])
print(csv1[~csv1.ID.isin(csv2.ID)])
```

Comment: have you tried getting the list of columns and comparing the ones in the union?

Comment: I removed the `r` and `excel` tags as this question does not directly relate to both those tools. Technically, there are no Excel CSVs. CSV is an industry data format which can be opened in Excel spreadsheets just like they can be in Notepad or other software.

Comment: Also, avoid asking too many broad questions and keep specific on a challenging single item you are facing. Attempted code does not appear to touch items 1-3. If you do not know how, read up on the many Pandas docs, tutorials, blogs, videos, etc. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a CSV file is **not** an Excel sheet but is a text file with conventions to represents rows containing fields. Each field contains a string representation of some data, with no indication of type. That means that any question about variable type is just non sense.

Now for your questions:

1. Compare/match the IDs from CSV1 to CSV2, show missing IDs in CSV1 or CSV2

   You can merge the dataframes with `indicator=True` and examine the special column `_merge`: it contains `left`, `right` or `both` if the id is present only in first, only in second or in both:

   ```
   pd.merge(excel1, excel2, how='outer', on='ID', indicator=True)[['ID', '_merge']]
   ```
2. See if StartDate in CSV2 is in between CSV1's Start Date and End Date

   Here again, merge both dataframes and ask (after converting the data columns):

   ```
   excel2['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(excel2['StartDate'])
   for col in ['StartDate', 'EndDate']:
       excel1[col] = pd.to_datetime(excel1[col])
   tmp = pd.merge(excel1, excel2, how='outer', on='ID', indicator=True)
   sd2between = (tmp.StartDate_x >= tmp.StartDate_y)&(tmp.StartDate_x<=tmp.EndDate)
   ```
3. Highlight differences in columns? (i.e. tell a user that 'Poop' is a column in CSV1 that doesn't appear in CSV2, and also highlight differences in Columns that are the same, i.e. one thing appears in CSV1 but not CSV2)

   I cannot really understand that part...

Comment: Thank you Serge! All of this helps so much. I edited the question so that 3 would be clearer.